# What is / why the fiber bundle connection one-form from a physics point of view?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, yang-mills

Take the Yang-Mills gauge theory for example. Gauge field $A$ is the pullback of the connection one-form to the base manifold. Other concepts of gauge theory also find their definition in fiber bundles, for example, pure gauge $g^{-1}dg$ is Maurer-Cartan one-form.

My question is that I lack a motivation to the fiber bundle connection one-form. The pullback of connection form is the gauge potential $A$ in physics, but there doesn't seem to be a direct physics counterpart for the connection form itself. So why are we going such a detour to define the fiber bundle and then connection forms but in physics everything seems to happen on the base manifold? From the physics point of view is there a necessity for the general connection forms? Can we formulate an alternative theory just on the base manifold?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How a physicist perceives gauge fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/319766/2451) and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic indeed related and very helpful reference